# Change colspan color in HTML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem. I would like to color only 1 word, and not the row's words.
e.g.: Would be great, if only passed became green, failed became red, and not testable became orange without coloring Last Result text. How can I refer to words, and coloring without Last Result text?

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
javascript:
(function() 
{ 
    var all = window.frames['mainframe'].frames['workframe'].document.getElementsByTagName("b");  
    for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++)  
        { 
            if(all[i].innerHTML == "Failed" )
                { 
                    all[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.textColor = "white"; 
                    all[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.color = "red"; 
                }  

            if(all[i].innerHTML == "Passed")
                { 
                    all[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "white"; 
                    all[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.color = "green"; 
                }  

            if(all[i].innerHTML == "Blocked")
                { 
                    all[i].innerHTML = "Not Testable"; 
                    all[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "white"; 
                    all[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.color = "orange"; 
                }  
        }  
    }
)();
```

And here is the HTML code:

```
<tr>
  <td width="20%" valign="top">
    <span class="label">Last Result:</span>
  </td>
  <td colspan="2">
    <b>Passed</b>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: this line all[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.textColor = "white"; will not set the color of text so you can just remove it from first condition

Comment: In your other comment, are you saying you cannot change the CSS or HTML markup, but instead only use JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, I use only JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

You should use if and else if to make your script working

Or take the script below, it is working

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('b').each(function (index, value) {
            var status = $(this).html();
            if (status === "Passed")
                $(this).css("color", "green");
            else if (status === "Failed")
                $(this).css("color", "red");
            else if (status === "Blocked") {
                $(this).css("color", "orange");
                $(this).html("Not Testable");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

`

and here is the html

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td width="20%" valign="top">
          <span class="label">Last Result:</span>
       </td>
       <td colspan="2">
           <b>Passed</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="20%" valign="top">
            <span class="label">Last Result:</span>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <b>Failed</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="20%" valign="top">
            <span class="label">Last Result:</span>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <b>Blocked</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  document.getElementsByTagName("b").innerHTML == "<span class='Failed'>Failed</span>"
  document.getElementsByTagName("b").innerHTML == "<span class='Passed'>Passed</span>"
```

In css, apply css to Passed and Failed classes

```
.Passed {
  // Your css
} 
.Failed {
  // Your css
}
```

Comment: The css and html code are not mine. This is a website's html and I couldn't edit

Comment: You don't have to add a `span` element. Just add the new class to the `b` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
(function() 
{ 
    var all1 = document.getElementsByTagName("b");  
    alert(all1[0].innerHTML);
    var max1 = all1.length;
    for (var i=0; i < max1; i++)  
        { 
            if(all1[i].innerHTML == "Failed" )
                { 
                    alert("failed");
                    all1[i].className = "failed"; 
                }  

            if(all1[i].innerHTML == "Passed")
                { 
                    alert("passed");
                    //all1[i].addClass("passed"); 
                    all1[i].className = "passed";
                }  

            if(all1[i].innerHTML == "Blocked")
                { 
                    alert("blocked");
                    //all1[i].innerHTML = "Not Testable"; 
                    all1[i].className = "blocked";
                }  
        }  
    }
)();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4xrkyqfq/1/

Changed around the code to fit your need. Hope it helps.